# Slicing the vector in R

Tags: r, vector, functional-programming

The authour just wrote:

“ The way we extract the rest of a vector by slicing will make R copy that subvector. The first time we call rest, we get the entire vector minus the first element, the second time we get the entire vector minus the first two, and so on. This adds up to about half the length of the vector squared. So while the search algorithm should be run in linear time, the way we extract the rest of a vector makes it run in quadratic time” (Functional Programming in R
Advanced Statistical Programming for Data Science, Analysis and Finance)

Can you help me to understand why while implementing the rest function every time the vector lessen by 1?

The example code is below:

```
lin_search <- function(element, sequence) {
  if (is_empty(sequence)) FALSE
  else if (first(sequence) == element) TRUE
  else lin_search(element, rest(sequence))
}

  is_empty <- function(x) length(x) == 0
  first <- function(x) x[1]

  rest <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 1) NULL else x[2:length(x)]
   }
```

Comment: Your question suggests you do not understand basic subsetting in R, you should really refer back to your teaching material. The answer would be clear if you understood what was happening with `x[2:length(x)]`

Comment: @Kevin Arseneau As I understand with `x[2:length(x)]` I choose from second to the n-th element of vector where n is equal to the vector length. Am I right?

Comment: What happens to the first element?

Comment: @Kevin Arseneau You mean when I do that second element become the first one in a new vector?

Comment: Give it a try and discover for yourself. If you are genuinely trying to learn, you must be willing to experiment... The joy is in the discovery and adventure

Comment: Thank you... I think I am an idiot ))

Comment: We all start from the same position, you are no better or worse than anyone at the beginning of the journey